# How to debug "Sugar CRM X Files May Only Be Used With A Sugar CRM Y Database."

Tags: sugarcrm

Sometimes one gets a message like:

```
Sugar CRM 6.4.5 Files May Only Be Used With A Sugar CRM 6.4.5 Database.
```

I am wondering how Sugar determines what version of the database it is using. In the above case, I get the following output:

```
select * from config where name='sugar_version';
+----------+---------------+-------+
| category | name          | value |
+----------+---------------+-------+
| info     | sugar_version | 6.4.5 |
+----------+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

cat config.php |grep sugar_version
'sugar_version' => '6.4.5',
```

Given the above output, I am wondering how to debug the output "Sugar CRM 6.4.5 Files May Only Be Used With A Sugar CRM 6.4.5 Database.": Sugar seems to think the files are not of version 6.4.5 even though the sugar_version is 6.4.5 in config.php; where should I look next?

Answer (score 1):

Two options for the issue:

Option 1: Update your database for the latest version.

Option 2: Follow the steps below and change the SugarCRM cnfig version.

```
mysql> select * from config where name ='sugar_version';
+----------+---------------+---------+----------+
| category | name          | value   | platform |
+----------+---------------+---------+----------+
| info     | sugar_version | 7.7.0.0 | NULL     |
+----------+---------------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Update your sugarcrm version to apporipriate :

```
mysql> update config set value='7.7.1.1' where name ='sugar_version';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: After Sugar refresh, it will prompt you to repair the config.php and after that, everything works back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The above commands seem to be correct. Sugar seems to check that config.php and the config table in the database contain the same version. In my case I was making the mistake of using the wrong database -- so if you're like me and tend to have your databases mixed up, double check in config.php that 'dbconfig' is indeed pointing to the right database.